# Query Google Play reviews via Cloud Storage API

Tags: api, google-api, google-play, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-storage

So Google offers monthly CSV exports of Google Play user reviews and provides a URL that looks like this: https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX/reviews/ (the actual URL contains numbers instead of X)

I can see that Cloud Storage has a Web API and wanted to try it out via the Google APIs Explorer, so I went to https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/storage.buckets.list, enabled OAuth and entered the the `pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX` part as project, but unfortunately all I got was a 400 error:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid argument."
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid argument."
}
}
```

Is there a way to access those CSV files via Web API?

Comment: pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX is bucket ID, not project ID

Comment: Do you know how I can determine the project ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/storage.objects.list?bucket=pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX&prefix=reviews%252F to list the CSV files. That said, the API explorer does not understand media requests, so to actually download them, you would have to do it separately via the `mediaLink` URL, which you can calculate if you know the bucket & object, e.g., [https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/*bucket*/o/*urlencodedobject*?alt=media](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/_bucket_/o/_urlencodedobject_?alt=media).

See [storage.objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) documentation for more info.

If you want to go to the UI rather than the API Explorer, you can try https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX/. If you owned the project (which isn't the case here; Google Play owns it), then you could select the project via https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/storage/browser and view all associated buckets and navigate to objects.